# メニューアイコン（縦に「・・・」）が表示されない

Tags: android

Android7のタブレットで動作していたアプリをAndroid9のタブレットにインストールした所、メニューアイコン（縦に「・・・」）が表示されなくなってしまいました。
対処方法をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示ください。
Android9のタブレットは「Lenovo E10」になります。

Answer (score 0):

Android OSのバージョンアップに伴い、メニューボタンは廃止されました。古いアプリはこの変更に対応していない可能性があります。

恐らく端末の下部に表示されるナビゲーションキーのうち、履歴ボタンを長押ししてみてください (大抵は戻るキーの反対側)。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。メニューボタンは廃止されたんですね。ナビゲーションキーは３種類「＜」「●」「■」が表示されておりそれぞれ長押ししてもメニューは出ませんでした。別途作らないといけないのでしょうか。